# Given linear trans. $T(x) = Ax$, $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 && - 2 \\3 &&1 \end{pmatrix}$, find trans of $x + y=2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given linear trans. $T(x) = Ax$, $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 && - 2 \\3 &&1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Find to what line x + y = 2 is transformed to.

Well, I've written the transfromation as $T(x) = (x - 2y, 3x + y)$. and I don't know how to continue from here.

The answer is: $-2x + 3y = 14$

I believe a hint will be sufficient, it is really easy but somehow I couldn't find any info. about how to approach this kind of exercise.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Write the line as $r(t)=(0,2)+t(2,-2)$ where $t$ is a real number and consider $T(r(t))$ using linearity.

Comment: Where did $t(2,-2$ come from? I'm confused.

Comment: $(2,-2)$ is a vector that is parallel to the line. Adding arbitrary multiples of it to any point on the line (in this case the y-intercept) will get you the entire line.

Answer (score 2):

The line is $$[1,1]\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right]=2\\
[1,1]A^{-1}A\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right]=2\\
\left([1,1]A^{-1}\right)T\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right]\right)=2$$

Comment: I totally understand nothing from your third line. I didn't learn that.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you're equivocating on what $x$ means. In some cases, you're using it as a vector; in others, as the vector's first component. Sometimes you use both in the same equation! No wonder you're confused!

As you've noticed, $x+y=2$ is equivalent to $y=2-x.$ Hence, letting $\vec v$ be an arbitrary vector on the line, we have $\vec v=\begin{bmatrix}t\\2-t\end{bmatrix}$ for some constant $t.$

Since $T(\vec v)=A\vec v=\begin{bmatrix}3t-4\\2t+2\end{bmatrix},$ as you can (and should) verify, put $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=A\vec v,$ then find constants $a,b,c$ such that $ax+by=c.$

Comment: Still having a little diffuclty. Maybe because I dont have paper near me. But I need to find x,y with the equation and that x,y that I found with t put on the transformation that is given?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding you, I'm afraid. The first $x,y$ are the components of each vector on the line. From this, we find that every vector on the line is of the form $\begin{bmatrix}t\\2-t\end{bmatrix}$ for some $t.$ This gives us the general form of the input vector $\vec v.$ The second $x,y$ are the components from the resulting output vector $A\vec v.$ Does that clarify things at all?

Answer (score 0):

Write your initial vector $x$ as $x=(t,2-t)$ then apply the transformation on it and see what you obtain. :)

Comment: $T(x,2-x) = (x + 2y - 4, 3x + y)$ I've reached that.

Comment: You need to start with $(t,2-t)$ as $t$ is your $x$ and $2-t$ your $y$. You see they add up to 2. You will get a new vector in terms of $t$ which satisfies the relation you want.